# Testing buffer list with Vader

Tags: vim, automated-tests

I am writing a `vim` plugin and I noticed a bug where temporary buffers are not cleaned up automatically.  I am using the [Vader](https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim) test framework plugin to test it and I would like to be able to verify the fix with a Vader test and prevent regressions.

I would use `:ls` command to verify the buffer list doesn't grow but I don't know how to access the output of this from Vader.

So, is it possible to use Vader to test that the buffer list doesn't grow?  Essentially, I just need to verify that the buffer list that is displayed is the same after executing my command as before. I don't need fine-grained check on the buffer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't specific to Vader, but you can capture the output of any Ex command via `:redir`, or more comfortably (in newer Vim versions) with [`:help execute()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29).

However, for the use case as you describe it, you don't need to parse the output of `:ls` at all: Buffers are allocated with increasing numbers, and the highest one can be obtained via `bufnr('$')`. So, just by storing the original value and comparing it with a later query, you can ensure that no additional buffers are created.

If you do need more more fine-grained checks on the buffers (your question isn't very clear on that), you can use `filter()` over all possible buffers, e.g. to obtain all listed buffers (or loaded buffers via `bufloaded()`):

```
:echo filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')
```

Comment: The problem is that my extension is just hiding the buffer by using the `nobuflisted` option on it.  So `bufnr('$')` gets incremented and the filter returns two different size arrays so they don't match after executing my command.

Comment: Also, the `execute()` solution doesn't work because the active buffer changes and the `#` and `%` markers change.  I am switching to a new window so this is expected.

Comment: Sorry, but none of that makes sense to me. You explicitly asked for capturing the output of `:ls` (what `execute()` is for) in your question, and now it's _not working_? And the filtering (adapted to your situation, which you didn't mention in your question, so I used `bufloaded`, but `buflisted` could be filtered on just as well) is exactly for not just comparing the largest buffer number returned by `bufnr('$')`.

Comment: `:ls` worked fine when I was eyeballing it but using it in the test doesn't work because it doesn't return an identical string. I didn't notice this because I didn't care which buffers had the `#` and `%` markers.  I apologize for not being clearer.  Switching to `buflisted(v:val)` works nicely, though.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah okay, great! Please don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it), then.

Comment: I will accept if you update your answer to say`buflisted`